# PostgreSQL trigram GIST vs. GIN indexes

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 database that contains 10M+ rows and some text fields that need similarity and `%word%`-like searches, so I decided to use trigram indexes.

Initially, I started to use GIN indexes, but now I am wondering whether I should rather use GIST.

The theory says:

- GIN index lookups are about three times faster than GiST
- GIN indexes take about three times longer to build than GiST
- GIN indexes are moderately slower to update than GiST indexes, but about 10 times slower if fast-update support was disabled (see Section 58.4.1 for details)
- GIN indexes are two-to-three times larger than GiST indexes

I have tried to create both `GIN` and `GIST` indexes and found the following in practice (on my dataset):

- For `LIKE '%word%'` queries, GIN is about the same speed (or even 5-20% slower) as GIST for the first time (when the index for the trigrams in the query are not cached yet).
- For `LIKE '%word%'` queries, GIN is about *5* times faster than GIST if the trigrams in the query were searched recently. GIST has always the same speed, regardless of cachedness.
- For `% 'word'` (similarity) queries, GIN is about *5-8* times *slower* than GIST, depending on the cachedness of the index.
- GIN is about 10% *smaller* than GIST. However, it seems to grow faster if there are `UPDATE` statements to the table. Unless, of course, I `VACUUM FULL` often enough.

So I see some discrepancies between theory and practice:

1. **speed**: GIST is often faster, except GIN is totally in memory (Can you ensure that in advance?), and even then only for `LIKE '%word%'` queries.
2. **size**: GIN is actually *smaller*. Is this typical for trigram indexes or is my case an outlier?
3. May the behaviour be significantly different in 9.4?
4. A last question: is it wise to use GIN if there are about 10-50k `UPDATE` statements and 5-10k `INSERT` statements daily, and weekly `VACUUM`is probably reasonable (not much usage on the weekend), or will it really hurt `UPDATE` and `INSERT` performance?

Comment: GIN indexes have gotten a [lot of improvements](http://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/events/698.en.html) in recent versions. What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: 9.1 currently, i will add that to the question